# sql SELECT * FROM syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get information from my table in php and mysql but the problem is that the table is all numbers. If i do

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Hello")
```

it works fine,

if i do

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 123")
```

it says that i have the incorrect syntax. Can someone please explain to me how to use numbers as a table name?

Comment: `123` is not a valid table name. And even though there are workarounds using it as a table name I strongly suggest you use a different one.

Comment: Here are the rules for naming objects in mysql - including tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `123`
```

you need to use the ` character before and after

Comment: Or even better give your tables sane names ;-)

Comment: Depends on the server configuration. Better link existing and better explaining material then actually individually answer that kind of question any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ` around your table name

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `123`")
```

Here are the rules for naming objects in mysql - including tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

To use reserved words, numbers, names with spaces and punctuation, etc. as column or table names, wrap it with backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `123`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote number like '123'

Answer (score 0):

Rules for naming objects, including tables in MySql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

```
Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
```

So using your syntax you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM `123`
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else has mentioned, you can wrap the table name in backticks to give you:

```
SELECT * FROM `123`
```

However, using numbers as a table name would be something you would have to consider very carefully. The reason being that it could lead to confusion later on. You would have to remember that for every query to this particular table you have to wrap it in backticks.

Without knowing why you are interested in naming a table in purely numbers it's hard to give better advice. But please consider carefully why you would want to use numbers for a SQL table name.